# How do I stimulate a forest fire in python?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a small project to learn python. This project creates a random forest, then sets the forest up on fire to stimulate a forest fire. So I managed to create the forest out using a function. The forest is just an array of 0s and 1s. 0 to represent water, 1 to present a tree.

So now I'm currently really stuck on how can I stimulate a forest fire with my array. I do know the logic behind how the fire should be started and spread, but I do not know how should I write it as a code.

The logic is that:

1. I'll use 2 to represent a fire, and 3 to represent burnt areas. So when trees get burned, all the 1s in the array will become 2, then followed by 3. Water, represented by 0, will not be affected. I think this part needs to be done with a for-loop. So one iteration of the loop will change 1 into 2, then the next for-loop will change 2 into 3, and repeat till the end of the array.
2. The fire needs to start from the center of the forest, so I need to figure out the positional index of the center of the array and check that if it is 1, and not 0 to initiate the fire. This can be done with a if-else condition.
3. The fire will then spread outwards to adjacent 1s in north, south, east, west direction, and so on and so forth.

So I'm having trouble writing up the loops to replace 1 with 2, then 2 with 3 such that it spreads from one tree to another.

I managed to write a function to create the random forest. The problem is with setting the forest up on fire. I've tried to write some for-loops, but I really have no idea how should I approach this problem.

```
#Define parameters for createForest Function. Sets the parameters for the forest too.
width = int(5) 
height = int(5) 
density = float(0.7) # probability of spawning a tree 
forest = [[]]

#Making a random forest
def createForest(width, height, density): 
    forest = np.random.choice(2, size=(width, height), p=[(1-density), density]) 
    return forest

print(createForest(width, height, density))
forest = createForest(width, height, density) # updates forest into the list
```

This would print out an array of 0s and 1s in random order:

```
[[1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: random forest is the name of a famous algorithm, you should not tag your question with it.

Comment: It sounds like you are building a 'Cellular Automaton' here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton The classic way of doing that is two keep *two* copies (or 'frames') of data; apply the rules to the existing 'grid' (or whatever the structure is), but keep the result in a new grid (or whatever) - at the end of each iteration; swap the old structure for the new one.

Comment: so your thoughts are correct; you will need a function that gives you the neighbours, and one that checks the number (0, 1, 2, 3...) and then does whatever is desired. Basically, one would implement this using a [Flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Not to solve the entire problem for you and take away all the fun, but I believe the missing piece is `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
forest = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10,10))
x, y = np.where(forest == 1)
print(x)  # up down
print(y)  # left right
```

This function outputs x,y coordinates in the matrix that you can use to perform tests on, and take actions with in adjacent cells (coordinates).

You can combine these coordinate pairs like so to iterate over them:

```
coord_pairs = np.vstack((x,y))
coord_pairs.shape  # (2, 48)
coord_pairs[0,:]  # x
coord_pairs[1,:]  # y

for k in range(coord_pairs.shape[1]):
    print(f"x:{coord_pairs[0,k]}, y:{coord_pairs[1,k]}")
```

The [state management as explained in this other answer on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55339123/3243159) will also be required.

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing a Cellular Automaton, and to simulate this you will need to create a copy of the array for your work. The basic algorithm would work as follows:

```
new_state = state.copy()
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        new_state[i,j] = calculate_new_cell(state, i, j)

state = new_state
```

(The `calculate_new_cell(state, i, j)` function is dependent on the rules of the cellular automaton.)